# Force codeigniter to redirect certain urls to subfolder with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have codeigniter installed in the root public_html.i have aslo a wordpress installed in a sub-folder. i need to redirect all urls excepts admin/anything to redirect to the wordpress in the sub-folder.
my folder structure as the following.

- application

  views

  controllers
- wordpress
- store

how i can do this using htaccess file ?

this is my htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Where are you current .htaccess rules? We can't help you modify something you haven't provided.

Comment: I added the htaccess content